# Open New Terminal From Finder When Terminal is Already Open

Tags: mac

Is there a setting that will let me open a NEW terminal window when I select the Terminal application from finder if one is already open?  What happens now is that it yanks me to the terminal window that is already open, which is a frustrating feature.
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can right click on any folder in Finder, select "Services" and "New Terminal at folder". A new Terminal window will pop up even if Terminal has other windows open. This will not change workspace. You can also create a keyboard shortcut for this command in System settings -> Keyboard -> Shortcuts -> Services.

If you don't have the option in the right-click window you can turn it on in System settings -> Keyboard -> Shortcuts -> Services -> "Files and folders"-heading and tick "New Terminal at folder".

If you have the option but it does not open a new windows, you need to enable it System settings -> Dock, set "Prefer tabs when opening documents" to "Manual" or "In full screen only" (both work, "Always" is default).

Answer (score 0):

In Catalina, and perhaps earlier macOSs, there are three ways to open a new Terminal window when a Terminal window is already on the desktop:

- From within Terminal, go to the Menu Bar, select > Shell > New Window
- From within Terminal, press Command-N to open a new window
- In any application, go to the Dock, right-click on Terminal's icon > New Window

Comment: Thanks.  So there is no way to have it open a new window on whatever desktop I am currently on without it yanking me over to the workspace that has the currently open terminal?

Comment: The first two bulleted methods can only be invoked from the workspace that has the currently open Terminal window; the new Terminal window will appear in that workspace. The third method, however, can be invoked from a workspace which doesn't display a Terminal window, provided you've previously set the Dock to persistently contain the Terminal icon. If you've done so, a left-click on the Terminal icon in the Dock will open a new Terminal window in the active workspace.

Answer (score 0):

In Monterey and possibly earlier, you can configure a few settings in Mission Control from the System Preferences menu.

Deselect the box that says "When switching to an application, switch to a Space with open windows for the application."

Now when you open an application, it will be activated in that Space. However, it will only open a new instance or window if there is not already a window of that app running in another Space.

My way of opening Terminal in the current Space with these settings:

1. Command + spacebar to open Spotlight Search.
2. Type "terminal" and press enter, which opens the Terminal application, but not a new instance, if one is already open in another Space.
3. Command + n to open a new Terminal instance.